# Adding and removing unique appended data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add buttons to rows for table control. THey should only ever appear once per row. I am having a lot of problems making sure the buttons are removed and then added to a new row if clicked, not removed if the same row is clicked, and so forth. Pretty much a toggle, but between different elements.

I am having problems where the buttons are remaining, the buttons are all disappearing, the buttons are not disappearing, etc. I really have bad control over this!

Please check out my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xvP4E/5/

```
    function tableTools(tableIdContainer){


    var addButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton addButton">ADD</button>';
    var infoButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton infoButton">INFO</button>';
    var editButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton editButton">EDIT</button>';
    var deleteButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton deleteButton">DELETE</button>';

    var tableTools = '<div class = "tableTools" style = "display:none;">' + infoButton + editButton + deleteButton + '</div>';


    if($('.tableTools').length){
        $('.tableTools').fadeOut(100,function(){
            $('.tableTools').remove();
        return tableTools;  
        }); 
    }else{
        return tableTools;  
    }   
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // div 1
    $('#wrapper').on('click', '#div1', function(){
        $(tableTools('#div1')).appendTo($(this)).fadeIn(500);
    });

    // div 2
    $('#wrapper').on('click', '#div2',function(){
        $(tableTools('#div2')).appendTo($(this)).fadeIn(500);

    });

    // div 3
    $('#wrapper').on('click', '#div3',function(){
        $(tableTools('#div3')).appendTo($(this)).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/xvP4E/10/

```
function tableTools(tableIdContainer, $row){


    var addButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton addButton">ADD</button>';
    var infoButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton infoButton">INFO</button>';
    var editButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton editButton">EDIT</button>';
    var deleteButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton deleteButton">DELETE</button>';

    var tableTools = '<div class = "tableTools" style = "display:none;">' + infoButton + editButton + deleteButton + '</div>';


    if($row.find('.tableTools').size()){
        $('.tableTools').fadeOut(100,function(){
            $('.tableTools').remove();
        return tableTools;  
        }); 
    }else{
        $('.tableTools').remove()
        return tableTools;  
    }   
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // div 1
    $('#wrapper').on('click', '#div1', function(){
        $(tableTools('#div1', $(this))).appendTo($(this)).fadeIn(500);
    });

    // div 2
    $('#wrapper').on('click', '#div2',function(){
        $(tableTools('#div2', $(this))).appendTo($(this)).fadeIn(500);

    });

    // div 3
    $('#wrapper').on('click', '#div3',function(){
         $(tableTools('#div2', $(this))).appendTo($(this)).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

Since you are indicating wether a button group should be shown or removed by checking the existent of one ANYWHERE you will just remove a button group when another row is clicked.
To fix this check if the *clicked* row contains a button group .

I made a quickfix by giving `tableTools` the additonal parameter `$row` and search in this for a button group and decide wether a button grouped will be removed or shown. Before showing of course old Buttons will be removed.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand what $row is doing. $row is an object, but I don't see in the function how it gets applied when tableTools i returned. edit: oh I am passing $(this) as $row! I see. Thanks!

Comment: Yea sorry I missed to let the tableTools let fadeOut...I think you will get that part on your own. I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

A much shorter version of your code would be as follows. I believe it should be much easier to debug and build upon if need be. Included also is a 'placeholder' for the `tableToolsButtons` -- the buttons wont be cause a `flicker' or cause themselves to disappear if they are clicked. In the`placeholder` handler you can decide whether or not to hide the buttons once done with them.

```
function tableTools(){

    var addButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton addButton">ADD</button>';
    var infoButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton infoButton">INFO</button>';
    var editButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton editButton">EDIT</button>';
    var deleteButton = '<button type = "button" class = "tableToolsButton deleteButton">DELETE</button>';    
    var tableTools = '<div class = "tableTools">' + infoButton + editButton + deleteButton + '</div>';

    var that = $(this);
    if( $('.tableTools').length ) {
        $('.tableTools').fadeOut(100,function() {
            $(this).remove();
            that.append(tableTools).fadeIn(500);        
        });
    } else {
        $(this).append(tableTools).fadeIn(500);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // div 1,2,3
    $('#wrapper').on('click', '#div1,#div2,#div3', tableTools)
    //tabletools buttons
    .on('click', '.tableToolsButton', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        //....
    });
});
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/xvP4E/38/)

Answer (score 0):

**If Control's What You Would Like...**

Then you should simplify this and get your thoughts together.

```
var buttons = ['add','info','edit','delete'],//define buttons
    butts = '',//set up buttons output
    tt = 'tableTools';//button parent class

for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {//for each button
    butts += '<button type="button" class="tableToolsButton '+buttons[i]+'Button">'+buttons[i]+'</button>';//print output
}

var  output = '<div class="tableTools" style="display:none;">'+butts+'</div>';//store output

function tableTools(el){    
    var go = el.children('.'+tt).length,//does current one have buttons?
        tabs = $('.'+tt),//get buttons
        fo = 100,//fade out
        fi = 500;//fade in

    if (tabs.length && !go){//there are buttons, but not on this one
        tabs.fadeOut(fo).remove();//so remove the buttons
        el.append(output).children('.'+tt).fadeIn(fi);//and add them to current
    } else if (go) {//if there are buttons on current
        tabs.fadeOut(fo).remove();//remove them
    } else if (!go) {//if no buttons exist on current
        el.append(output).children('.'+tt).fadeIn(fi);//make them
    }

    //prevent on button click
    $('.tableToolsButton').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        //add code for buttons here
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper > div').on('click', function(){ tableTools($(this)); });//run on click
});
```

*That way it's much easier to edit & maintain.*

[**Made a fiddle...**](http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/yTVLW/)

Comment: wow. so many ways to code. sometimes i feel like programming has 'styles'. Is this a style or just experience?

Comment: This is to make it easier to maintain, and easier to understand. The less you need to edit, the smaller the margin for error becomes. The less you repeat yourself, the clearer your path becomes.So by defining the things you may need to change outside of the operation it allows you to make changes without having to edit the operation code. I just like to make things simple and try to make sure the code operations can be read aloud and easily understood. This still has much room for improvement, but it's a path that is much more clear (to me at least).

Comment: Coding certainly has different styles, they just don't show up as much until the code has been refactored past a certain point so you can see a clear path of the way they think about putting things together. If you find yourself having to type the same thing more than once, stop and think things through first. How are you going to change this later, or reuse it somewhere else? How are you, or someone else that may need to edit this, going to understand what's going on 6 months from now? Instead of saying "Let's do A, then B, then C, ...", think "Let's do X which will take care of A,B,C,...".